# .gitignore Django project's __pycache__ folder

Tags: git

I have been trying a lot of different commands but nothing seems to be working to Git ignore all the `__pycache__` folders and their files in my project. I have written the following code in my `.gitignore` file and need help to ignore all `__pycache__` in any subfolder of my Django project:

```
**/__pycache__/**

frontend_react_app/node_modules/
frontend_react_app/build
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
__pycache__/
```

Note that if the files are already tracked in a commit, you need to also follow the directions in: [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/9835872)

Comment: I have edited my `.gitignore` with your code but in my VS Code - Source Control tab, some modified `.pyc` files in the `__pycache__` folders are still appearing. Is it not ignoring them or because they already are in my committed repo, they will always be appearing?

Comment: Did you run `git rm -r --cached path/to/__pycache__`? Note the `-r` flag.

Comment: So in order for the gitignore to work, I need to delete all the `__pycache__` folders in my git repo online?

Comment: No. You simply run the `git rm -r --cached` command locally, commit the changes and push.